# Intent Activity not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm doing a basic activity of moving from one page to another. Everything was going perfect until I get two pages deep into the app. I used the same exact code for each page class, put the activities in the manifest and made sure all words were spelled correctly, etc., but the intent doesn't do anything when I try to go three pages deep. There are no error messages in the log at all. When I click on a button on the third page, it just turns blue but doesn't move to the next page like the previous pages. Here's my code:

from page 1 to 3:

Page1:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     Button button;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton(); }

     public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

       button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

       button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainMenu.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

        });

        }
       }
```

Page 2: has more buttons...

```
     public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

  Button button;
  Button button2;
  Button button3;
  Button button4;
  Button button5;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
    addListenerOnButton();
    }

 public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

   button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
   button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
   button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
   button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, OneMain.class);
                    startActivity(intent);   
    }       
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TwoMain.class);
                    startActivity(intent);   
      }       
     });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ThreeMain.class);
                    startActivity(intent);   
    }       
    });

    button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FourMain.class);
                    startActivity(intent);   
    }       
    });

    button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FiveMain.class);
                    startActivity(intent);   
    }       
    });

      }
     }
```

Page 3:

```
  public class OneMain extends ActionBarActivity {

   Button button;


    @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.one_main);

 }

public void addListenerOnButton() {

final Context context = this;



button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alphabet.class);
                    startActivity(intent);   
    }       
});



       }


      }
```

I also made sure I put in all the imports. Someone help. I'm stuck :(.

Here is the manifest xml:

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.juwar74.alarabic"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >



 <uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:launchMode="singleTop"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
 <activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MainMenu" >
</activity>
 <activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".OneMain" >
</activity>

<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".TwoMain" >
</activity>

<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".ThreeMain" >
</activity>

<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".FourMain" >
</activity>

<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".FiveMain" >
</activity>

<activity
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:name=".OneVoc" >
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the code for the Alphabet.class

```
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

        public class Alphabet extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alphabet);

        }
       }
```

Comment: Alphabet.class is not registered in manifest.

Comment: i don't see the alphabetclass in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

in page3 you never called  `addListenerOnButton()` .

```
public class OneMain extends ActionBarActivity {

   Button button;
   @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.one_main);
          // HERE you missed addListenerOnButton();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
   android:name=".Alphabet " >
</activity>
```

You missed this in the manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

First call `addListenerOnButton()` in OneMain.java after `setContentView`.
Then check manifest.
Alphabet.class is not registered in manifest.

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".Alphabet" >
</activity>
```

After adding it, make sure you are rendering correct xml in Alphabet.java